# Cloudflare seems to be blocking Google Analytics onclick events

Tags: google-analytics, cloudflare

I'm trying to set up events with trigger `onclick` with Google Analytics. I have followed the docs, and many examples online. I have a feeling Cloudflare is somehow stopping the events from logging because they add code to each button.

How my button is locally

```html
<a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'go-link', 'hero-section', 'theTitle');" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank" href="/go?id=1266">Try {Title}</a>
```

How my button is when live (due to Cloudflare)

```html
<a onclick="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; ga('send', 'event', 'go-link', 'hero-section', 'theTitle');" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank" href="/go?id=1266">Try {Title}</a>
```

Am I doing something wrong? And if, what is the issue & if it is indeed Cloudflare, how do I prevent them from stopping the Google Analyics `onclick` from triggering?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [Rocket Loader](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168056-What-does-Rocket-Loader-do-) could be affecting your tracking code. Rocket Loader is a feature that attempts to improve the page loading time by asynchronously loading Javascript. Sometimes this optimization can interfere with the behavior of the scripts. You can find the toggle to enable / disable it in the **Speed > Optimization** tab, and check again if your event is firing correctly.